# Passing Context.User.Identity.GetUserId() to an SQL statement returns no data

Tags: asp.net, select, sqldatasource, formview

I have the following code but it doesn't seem to work. The <%= Context.User.Identity.GetUserId() %> has a value in the database but it's not returning any data..... Thanks

```
   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="owner_information" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT TOP 1  [imgMain_user], [IDname] FROM [View-EditorLinks] WHERE ([IDuser] = @IDowner)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="IDowner" Type="String" DefaultValue="<%= Context.User.Identity.GetUserId() %>" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Have you fired up a debugger to verify that `Context.User.Identity.GetUserId()` is returning what you expect, and have you tried replacing `Context.User.Identity.GetUserId()` with a hard-coded value to make sure that the data source returns the rows you expect?  There are several places this could be failing, let's try to narrow down where the problem actually lies.

Comment: I tested the page with the following code in the aspx head section and it worked well <% if (Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
       {
           owner_information.SelectParameters["IDowner"].DefaultValue = Context.User.Identity.GetUserId();
       } %>